# How does licensing work with Vagrant Windows boxes?

Tags: windows, vagrant, licensing

Can a single Windows license be shared between a team (akin to installing on a physical or virtual server) for hosting Vagrant boxes?  The [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/) don't seem to address this issue and all the examples use open source *nix distributions.

To be more specific: I have a QA environment that currently resides on a physical machine, can I simply buy another license to re-create that environment as a Vagrant box and allow my team to share and develop against it?

It seems like a gray area since the box is constantly being created and destroyed within the confines of a parent O/S.

Comment: No.  If multiple instances exists of the same vagrant box at the same time it would require multiple licenses.  Otherwise IBM would avoid the costs of those 10,000 license